# Populate cell in sheet 2 with particular answer based on multiple cells completion status in sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets

Sheet 1 will have 5 cells (in a single row and associated with a specific ID) that need to be filled with 5 dates. If all 5 dates appear, Sheet 2 will state "yes" adjacent to the same ID. If only some of the 5 dates are populated in Sheet 1, Sheet 2 will state "partially". And if none of the dates are populated in Sheet 1, Sheet 2 will state "no".

I'm working in google sheets and don't know what formula to use to confirm the correct ID from sheet 1 to sheet 2 (vlookup?) and then to populate based on 5 criteria.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you supply a link to a sample sheet?  Also, if not using excel, remove the excel-formula tag.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SSVamuCBu1f1-gEgAb43rdbe-3fTCfFT39A_z9mcv8s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What I'm hoping to create is a formula that would see the subject ID from sheet 1 and populate the completion status of the 5 cells associated for that subject with a "yes", "no" or "partial".